# Convert SQL Server date to As400 date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, db2

I have a date in SQL Server in this format: `1/1/2013 14:15:16`

I want to convert it to `2013-1-1-14.15.16.000000`

I did this in C# by doing something like this

```
dateValue.toString("YYYY-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.000000")
```

Is there a format conversion that I should use?

I would prefer to do it in c# code.

Comment: I don't think you've said exactly *where* you want to do this: in SQL Server code, in DB2 code or somewhere else? Please also mention your version of SQL Server; 2012 has the [`FORMAT` function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634924.aspx) but previous versions don't.

Comment: Seems this may have been tagged with the wrong database...? Is it DB2 (which I answered for) or SQL Server?

Comment: DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP data types do not have any format in databases, they are typically stored as numbers. You shouldn't need to bother formatting anything if you use variables of the right data type in the application (not sure about C#, a Java example would be java.sql.Timestamp) and bind them to the SQL statements executed against whatever database.

Comment: What type of OS is your DB2 server running on?  If DB2 is running on a more powerful server such as a Power System or mainframe.  Are you transferring a whole table to a new table, or doing inserts?  If you are putting the value in a DB2 timestamp, then I believe you want to convert it to 2013-01-01-14.15.16.000000 with leading zeros on each part.

Comment: By the way, IBM hasn't shipped an AS/400 since 2000.  The box running DB2 is most likely properly known as a Power System running IBM i OS (6.1 or 7.1), or perhaps an iSeries running i5/OS.  Many people still cling to the names of the older products, but this is somewhat like saying that you run SQL Server on an IBM PC XT.

Comment: So you've done it in C#, but would prefer to do it in C#.  Are you asking how to reformat a string containing `1/1/2013 14:15:16` rather than a value in a `DateTime`?

Comment: No. I was wondering if there is a c# lib that I can call. The method I used seems like a hack.  I was hoping to see something like string isoDateX = Convert.ToDate(dateValue,someISODateFormat).toString()

Answer (score 1):

```
select Replace( Replace( Convert( VarChar(26), SysDateTime(), 121 ), ' ', '-' ), ':', '.' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could simply [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on the SQL Server side.  Nice and simple.

(Caveat:  I'm a DB2 for i guy, not a SQL Server expert)